# Chrome selection look & feel - how do I "contain" a selection within the boundary of a div?

Tags: html, google-chrome, selection

I'm having trouble containing the selection in chrome to a div. It wants to make it a lot wider. Playground is here:
http://jsbin.com/ujafow/28/

If you select from 1.2(a) in my example up to 1.2 you can see that the selection border goes all the way out to the edge of 1.... I'd like to contain it within 1.2 since the entire selection is within that. Interestingly it doesn't go all the way out to the edge of the outer div, so there must be some way of containing it? Other browsers (e.g. ie) seem to just select the text and everything is hunky dory.

Does anybody know what I need to do to make it stay within logical borders?

PS. I've tried with lists with the same result: http://jsbin.com/ujafow/7
PPS. Tables work well but it's contentEditable so that complicates things for me since I don't want them having to edit a table.
PPS. There is a long outstanding [defect for this in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12269).

Edit: It looks like it draws the selection to the edge of whatever is made contentEditable - if I make the whole thing contentEditable, it draws right out to the edges. The only thing that seems to stop it is if there is a div on the left... maybe I can put an empty div on either side to restrict the drawing of the selection to just that area...?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like adding `overflow: hidden;` to `.npse` in the CSS will fix it.

I'd previously been trying your solution...which worked, but was very awkward to work with.  But if this is correct, don't thank me... thank @ralph.m here who answered my extension to the question:

[::select pseudo-element ignored in fill space, selection going out of bounds...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367280/select-pseudo-element-ignored-in-fill-space-selection-going-out-of-bounds)

Just providing it as an answer to close the loop so you can accept it if it's right--to save others who come across this question some time!

Comment: What's annoying is how much time I spent doing this stuff when overflow: hidden; was all I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove "contenteditable=false" from your title spans. At least, that worked for me.

EDIT: got it to work. [check here.](http://jsfiddle.net/LcrbP/)
You just have to figure out how to remove the changeable size and the little thing in the corner.

```
textarea {
background:transparent;
border:none;
}
textarea:focus {
border:none;
outline:none;
}
```

EDIT EDIT: use this

```
textarea {
resize: none;
}
```

EDIT EDIT EDIT: okay, finally got it.

```
<p  contentEditable="true"><span class="counter" 
contentEditable="false">1.2</span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Cras scelerisque molestie nisi, ut accumsan libero rutrum non. Ut non scelerisque 
lacus. Proin ornare rhoncus lobortis. Nullam id laoreet justo, et bibendum justo. Etiam 
luctus ligula faucibus, eleifend augue tempor, dapibus nunc.</p>
```

It works [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/hPYyN/1/) Just remove "contenteditable" from the body and add it to each individual element. You'll have to remove the border and outline on :focus, though.

P.S.: :P :D for OCD

Comment: Really? This still selects far too much when selecting in 1.2(a)  for me in chrome 28.0.1500.95 m: http://jsbin.com/ujafow/29/

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't understand your question. For the overflowing select, I don't really know if you can do anything about that. It's like that on most websites. There is one thing you can try; I'm not sure if it will work, though. Try a textarea with border and background completely removed.

Comment: By making individual elements contentEditable, you stop yourself being able to select from 1.2 into anywhere else. So whilst it's fixed the look of the selection, it's broken the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by putting an absolute positioned div to the left of it (which I've called the "title-container" in the code below). It then contains the selection nicely. The title-container div is a child of the elementToContain div. The size of the div's is set via js.

```
.elementToContain {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5em; 
}

.title-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0em;
    bottom: 0em;
    border: ridge red 0.1em;
    left: 0;
    padding-right: 0.25em;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -user-select: none;
}
```